# Every Spanning Set for V contains Least or Most n vectors? or both

Tags: linear-algebra

If V = span(v1, v2, ... vn), then every spanning set for V contains at least n vectors. That is true.

If V = span(v1, v2, ... vn), then every spanning set for V contains at most n vectors. That is true.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Both statements are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}$ and let $A=\{1,2\}$, then $V=span\ A$ but $B=\{1\}$ and $C=\{1,2,3\}$ also span $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, both the statements are false.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a set of vectors $V$ spans a vector space $X$ if every $x \in X$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors from $V$. But if this is true, then every element of $x$ can certainly be written as a linear combination of vectors from, say, $V \cup \{w\}$ for any $w \not\in V$. One simply uses the representation of $x \in X$ as a linear combination of vectors from $V$, all of which are also vectors in $V \cup \{w\}$.

Thus, you have two spanning sets of cardinality $n$ and $n+1$. In this manner, you are always assured the existence of a larger spanning set (unless $V = X$, which trivially spans itself). And since "unnecessarily large" spanning sets such as $V \cup \{w\}$ exist, you are not guaranteed that every spanning set you take will have the smallest possible cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

If $(v_1, v_2, ... v_n)$ are linearly independent, then the first one can be true. And if the spanning set for $V$ contains $n$ vectors, we call it basis. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)

In the above case, $(v_1, v_2, ... v_n)$ is a basis.